# Ajax Toolkit TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How do I get ride of the orange border? I'm using Chrome and that border shows up now where in computed styles!

[image: TabContainer]

Answer (score 2):

[Remove Safari/Chrome textinput/textarea glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935559/remove-safari-chrome-textinput-textarea-glow)

As per the link provided

```
textarea, input { outline: none; }
```

Tried, tested & worked :P