# Remove Blue Lines on Selected Mapping Point

Tags: html, css

How do I get rid of the blue lines that display when I select part of a mapped image. Example below:
[image: Blue Line Example]

```
<img src="http://earlgreyblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/resources-for-bloggers_02.png" alt=""   usemap="#Map"/>
<map name="Map" id="Map" outline:none; >
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.nooralqahtani.com/writing-blog-post/" shape="rect"   coords="319,606,0,322" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.marketyourcreativity.com/2014/09/5-must-have-apps-for-  creative-business/" shape="rect" coords="324,605,639,260" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://emberandmarch.com/five-minute-disconnect/" shape="rect"   coords="638,251,323,2" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.weareflourishandprosper.com/#!WHY-BLOGGERS-SHOULDNT-BE-  EXPECTED-TO-WORK-FOR-FREE/cyv2/053CC54E-BAA7-4BCB-8E89-8857A32C64EC" shape="rect" coords="2,316,318,3"   />
</map>
```

Comment: check my update in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a good idea to use a reset CSS. add this at the top of your CSS file

```
img, a {border:none, outline: none;}
```

**OR**

```
img{border:none, outline: none;}
```

You can also limitate the scope and only remove border on some images by doing so:

```
.myClass img{border:0;}
```

hope this helps :)

### Update:

I show in your code there is `outline:none;` instead `style="outline:none;"` correct it

**CSS:**

```
img, map area{
    outline: none;
}
```

This should work cross browser

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I am trying to fix this for this one post, while keeping everything else the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code in your CSS:

```
area:focus {
     outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I lied, this still didnt work. I will update the code.

Comment: It looks like all this does is move where the lines show up... very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

From:

[Remove Safari/Chrome textinput/textarea glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935559/remove-safari-chrome-textinput-textarea-glow)

And

[This tutorial](http://red-team-design.com/get-rid-of-safari-blue-input-outer-glow-once-and-for-all/), you can just use:

```
outline: none;
```

to remove that glow, so if it is an image map, you need to add the above css rule to that image map element, you haven't posted some code so i cant really show you the correct code that you need to add or change.

Considering your code, following should work just fine.

```
img, Map area{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I already have that in the code. I will try to upload the code better, not sure why it is only showing one line.

Comment: Where would you add:  
    img, Map area{
    outline: none;
    }