# Disable highlight of selected element

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to disable the highlight of selected elements.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: example with blue glow]

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: example without blue glow]

The only way for there to be no blue glow is to click where there isn't an image button, but even then it reappears every time on the first button when I click the extension icon.

I came across the question [Remove Safari/Chrome textinput/textarea glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935559/remove-safari-chrome-textinput-textarea-glow) earlier on StackOverflow, but the CSS properties `-webkit-appearance`, `outline`, `outline-color`, and `outline-style` did not fix anything.

I have a GitHub repository at https://github.com/Usernamer/EmojiChrome.

Comment: Do you need keyboard control in the popup, or are mouse clicks the only interaction you're looking for?

Comment: @Xan It relies solely on mouse clicking. I tried keyboard control, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This glow is the highlight of the focused input element.

You need a CSS rule for the `:focus` pseudo-selector (inline for example, but best contained in a separate file)

```html
<style>
  input:focus { outline: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Can I do this via HTML using: `<script>input:focus { outline: none; }</script>`?

Comment: Why would it be, if it's CSS, not JS? Besides, inline JS code is not allowed in extensions.

Comment: Ah, looking at your code I see the problem. Well, live and learn: [MDN on `<style>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style). Putting it in a separate CSS file will probably be cleaner still.